# Is there a good oh-my-zsh or sublime text 2 plugin to make rails queries more readable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminal, zsh, sublimetext2, iterm

When running a rails console in iterm2 and querying the database, it spits out the results of the query in a big, comma-delimited blob. Is there a good plugin to format the output of a console query in a little more readable fashion?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe pretty-printing can help here? I currently use [awesome_print](https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print/).

So, instead of

```
User.all # or whatever another query you're running
```

you will write this

```
ap User.all
```

And you should get much nicer results.

Comment: Could use a little help... I installed the gem into the root directory, but I'm not sure where I need to require it in order to use it in the console.

Comment: Yes, you need to require it. `require 'awesome_print'`